# How to maintain session in webview after login from activity?

Tags: java, android, session, webview, android-volley

I am using volley library for calling web services from my android application. Once the user has logged in from activity, I want it to be auto-login to a Webview which is shown in the next activity. Without forcing a user to log in again in Webview, I want it to maintain a session. Can anyone please provide a solution to achieving this?

Comment: you can use SharredPreference for this.

Comment: Can you please explain how can I use them to maintain session in Webview?

Comment: Generally, you will get login success response from your web services, so you store any login credential like (eg: username, token) into SharePreference, and then when in your next or other every activities, check that your store login credential in previous step, if credential exist(you can assume as session), you can do other stuff like auto login, something.

Comment: Thanks, but that works in case I have to do stuff on an activity. Here, what I need is that I am passing a URL to Webview, it is showing me you are not authorized. So, all I want is to open that page in Webview successfully.

Comment: so does your login process returns any auth token kind of ?

Comment: I am sorry, no it does not return and token.

Comment: What do you mean by session then? I guess there should be some token which you receive from the server when user logs in